# android viewpager, currently active view

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to get the currently shown view on screen , I need it to implement the next previous button for viewpager, how can I get currenly shown view on screen, is there any method like getCurrentItemPosition, I have looked into doc and there seems nothing like that which is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageListener());
```

and keep updating the current page when you get a call to the listener. mCurrentPage will give you the required result.

```
private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                 mCurrentPage = position;
            }
}
```

Comment: The code above gives you the current position, not the current view. How do I get a reference to the current view with or without the current position?

Answer (score -1):

If you're not doing anything special to ViewPager it should contain child views with same order as in adapter. I'm using following code

```
View view = mViewPager.getChildAt(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Also you can rely on position parameter from method `onPageSelected(int position)`

Comment: This doesnt work right when there are more than 3 views in the pager. See my answer.